# QGIS - raster calculator syntax

Tags: qgis, raster, raster-calculator

I am having problems using the raster calculator. Some pixels of my GeoTIFF file have the value 255 on bands 1, 2 and 3. I want to replace this value with 0 on the three bands.

I tried with this formula but it does not look good:
("test@1" != 255)+("test@2" != 255)+("test@3" != 255) * "test"

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the raster calculator you could reclassify your raster bands. 
This tread lists a few options: [How to reclass a raster with reclassify grid values in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/121532/how-to-reclass-a-raster-with-reclassify-grid-values-in-qgis)

Inside QGIS you can use the GRASS module r.reclass. Reclassifying rules have to be specified in a text file or directly. I am not sure if this works directly for all bands or if you have to process each band separately.

Comment: Ok thanks. Do you now the syntax for my problem ? I have try the same syntax  : https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/77626/how-to-reclassify-a-raster-tiff-with-multiple-bands. But it's not working

Comment: Check for more information: https://grass.osgeo.org/grass70/manuals/r.reclass.html

You could try to apply this to each band separately maybe? 
255 = 0

It is hard to test without sample data.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it with raster calculator at once. Each layer needs to be converted first and then, you can stack them. Use:

```
("test@1" != 255)*"test@1"
```

Cause:

If `"test@1" != 255` value is 1 in result and `"test@1" = 255` value is 0 in result